# Using temporary AWS credentials to call an API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to make an API call to AWS in Node.js using temporary credentials taken from the STS service. I'm going off the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) under the **Using Temporary Security Credentials with APIs** paragraph. I'm also signing my request using the [aws4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) npm package. I'm struggling to get this request to work correctly. I keep getting 403 errors saying that I'm missing the Authentication Token. I don't know where/how to put the `x-amz-security-token` in the request.

```
const opts = {
      service: 'execute-api',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      qs: {
        'x-amz-security-token': tempCreds.Credentials.SessionToken
      }
    };

    aws4.sign(opts, {accessKeyId: tempCreds.Credentials.AccessKeyId, secretAccessKey: tempCreds.Credentials.SecretAccessKey});

      let response = await rp({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: config.preRegistration.baseUrl_US,
        opts,
        body: load
      });
```

I've made sure my tempCredentials are correct too, so it's not a problem with those credentials, it's how I'm building the request.

Here's my error for reference:

```
Error: {"name":"StatusCodeError","statusCode":403,"message":"403 - \"{\\\"message\\\":\\\"Missing Authentication Token\\\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that your api "Invoke URL" does not exist or you did not configure it correctly.